# Efficient simulation of brownian motion with drift in R

Tags: r, performance, simulation

I want to efficiently simulate a brownian motion with drift d>0, where the direction of the drift changes, if some barriers b or -b are exceeded (no reflection, just change of drift direction!).
A `for`-loop is the simple way doing this

```
 step<-0.1 #step size
 sig<-1 #sign of drift
 T<-10^4 #length of process
 b<-300; d<-0.5#barrier and drift
 W<-rep(NA,(T/step))
 W[1]<-0
 for (i in 2:(T/step))
 {
  if (W[i-1]>b) {sig<- -1} #change drift to -1
  if (W[i-1]< -b) {sig<-1} #change drift to +1
  W[i]<-W[i-1]+rnorm(1,d*sig*step,sqrt(step))
 }
```

Of course this loop takes much time in R especially for small step size.
Therefore, I am interested in a more efficient solution maybe using vectorial operations or the `apply()`-command. (in case of a simple brownian motion I can use `cumsum(rnorm())`, is a similar solution possible here?)

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a recursive calculation for `W[i]` and `sig` which also does a bit of logic at each step.  There's probably not much you can do in R to reduce the execution times by a large factor  but there are a couple of things that will reduce times by almost 50%.  In particular rather than calling `rnorm` on each step, vectorize this calculation by calling `rnorm` once with `mean=0` to compute `num_step` values and store the result. In each step of the loop, the value from this vector is added to the mean for that step. The logic determining the value of `sig` can also be simplified a bit.  The code with timings for the posted approach and the new code are:

```
  step<-0.1         #step size
  T<-10^4           #length of process
  b<-300; d<-0.5    #barrier and drift

  print(system.time({
    sig <- 1           #sign of drift
    set.seed(123)      # set seed
    W<-rep(NA,(T/step))
    W[1]<-0
    for (i in 2:(T/step))
    {
      if (W[i-1]>b) {sig<- -1} #change drift to -1
      if (W[i-1]< -b) {sig<-1} #change drift to +1
      W[i]<-W[i-1]+rnorm(1,d*sig*step,sqrt(step))
    }
  }))

  print(system.time({
    sig <- 1                # reset value of sig
    set.seed(123)           # reset seed
    num_steps <- trunc(T/step)
    W1 <- numeric(num_steps)
    ep <- rnorm(num_steps, 0, sqrt(step))
    for (i in 2:num_steps)  {
      if(abs(W1[i-1]) > b) sig <- ifelse( W1[i-1] >b, -1, 1) 
      W1[i] <- W1[i-1]+d*sig*step +ep[i-1]
    }
  }))
```

The results of the two calculations, `W` and `W1`, should be identical.